# django settings.py value error

Tags: python, django

I am setting up a django project(for the first time).

I tried to configure, but despite its showing some value error.

Here is the settings.py

## settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    ('asit', 'lipun4u@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'C:\\Users\\asit\\workspace\\tutu\\src\\sqlite.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'
    
SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:\\django\\media'

MEDIA_URL = ''

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

SECRET_KEY = 'secret_key'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = ''

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'C:\\django\\template\\'
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^tutu/', include('tutu.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

The error is

```
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

Empty module name

Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in import_module, line 35
```

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: When do you get the error?

Comment: I get the error for the url http://localhost:8000/admin.

Comment: settings looks fine, paste the views/urls would probably be helpful.

Comment: `ROOT_URLCONF` seems to be empty.

Comment: Try replacing all the double backslashes in your paths with forward slashes. This is counter intuitive on windows, but django will convert them as needed. This error is probably happening because django is choking on the backslashes in your db name/path. See the note under TEMPLATE_DIRS.

Comment: @CIGuy I replaced all double backslashes with forward slashes...still the same error message is coming

Comment: See Johns answer below, your empty Root Url Conf is also a problem.

Comment: @Aya What should be the value of ROOT_URLCONF ? I am running this on a standalone windows 7 machine . So i don't have any url .

Comment: @Phoenix If you don't know what it should be, I'd recommend reading the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/) before you carry on - the URL dispatcher is covered in part 2. You don't technically need a `ROOT_URLCONF` if you intend to completely bypass Django's URL dispatcher, and implement your own in middleware, but it's kinda unusual to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have empty `ROOT_URLCONF`. It does not have any default value defined, so you should provide actual url config for your project here. Most likely it's just `yourprojectname.urls`, like this

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'yourprojectname.urls'
```

See django [URLDispacther docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-ROOT_URLCONF) for details.